# Integrating JasperReports with Spring

Tags: java, spring, jasper-reports

As you know, when using integrating *JasperReports* views and *Spring*, the report data key in your xml file takes just one key, I'll demonstrate below. But what if I have more than one key, matter of fact I can't determine the number of objects that is going to be in my map.

How do I solve this?

This is my jasper-views.xml

```xml
<bean id = "toPdf"
class = "org.springframework.web.servlet.view.jasperreports.JasperReportsPdfView"
p:url= "classpath:src/newpackage/tcoReport.jasper"
p:reportDataKey="dSource"
/>
```

Comment: As you know, a report takes only one datasource which is iterated in order to display details. Maybe try to elaborate a little better and explain what data structure you're trying to send to the report

Answer (score 0):

i would recommend implementing your own PdfView.

i'll demonstrate it:

```
public class JasperPdfView extends AbstractView {

public JasperPdfView(){
    setContentType("application/pdf");
}

@Override
protected void renderMergedOutputModel(Map<String, Object> model, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws Exception {
    final JasperPrint print = (JasperPrint)model.get("jasper_print");
    JasperExportManager.exportReportToPdfStream(print, response.getOutputStream());
}
```

}

i have a service that creates my JasperReport object which I'll pass to the View.

```
@Override
public JasperPrint generate(ReportContext ctx) throws SQLException {
        Resource res = resourceLoader.getResource(ctx.getFile());
        JasperReport report = JasperCompileManager.compileReport(res.getInputStream());

        HashMap<String, Object> map = Maps.newHashMap();
        map.putAll(ctx.getParams());
        map.put("from", ctx.getFrom().toDate());
        map.put("to", ctx.getTo().toDate());
        JasperPrint print = JasperFillManager.fillReport(report, map, dataSource.getConnection());
        return print;
}
```

my Controller generates calls the service and puts the JasperReport on the model.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{reportName}")
public void printReport(@PathVariable final String reportName, final ParameterForm form, final ModelMap model)
        throws SQLException {
    final ReportContext ctx = reports.get(reportName).build();
    ctx.setFrom(form.getFrom());
    ctx.setTo(form.getTo());
    ctx.getParams().put("customerId",form.getCustomerId());
    model.put("jasper_print", reportService.generate(ctx));
}
```

the JapserPdfView is determined through a ContentNegotiatingViewResolver.